# Using JNA or JNI to simulate keys held down in Windows

Tags: java, windows, keyboard, keyboard-hook

I want to simulate a keypress in Java. Others have tried this using Robot. This only allows an atomic keypress, where I want to simulate a key hold (for a second, say) and release. So, I need to use JNA or JNI.

I investigated JNative, but this seems to be for consuming key events at an OS level, not generating them at an OS level. How can I generate such events from Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc:

```
void java.awt.Robot.keyPress(int keycode)

Presses a given key. The key should be released using the keyRelease method.
```

EDIT: Adding a sample:

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    System.out.println("You have 2 seconds to jump to the target window...");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_A);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Ouput on the target window:

```
    aA
```

(I know this is not what you want but I added it for future readers as a reference so they don't think there is a bug in the JavaDoc or Robot)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, using Robot you can hold down a key for second.

```
Robot r = ...
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
Thread.sleep(1000);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work. See this other post on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784414/simulate-a-key-held-down-in-java because doing keyPress, then wait, then keyRelease, doesn't work like you would expect. Another answer suggests using another thread for timing while issuing repeated Robot.keyPress() calls, but that doesn't do a "press and hold" either, it just does a lot of individual key presses. I am trying to interface to a program that needs the low-level events - Robot isn't working at all. Hence why I need to interface to the Windows API in some way. Thanks

Comment: is the Robot keypressed work outside the JFrame?
I wonder if i could apply the same thing by this code....