# Robot's keyPress() doesn't work as should

Tags: java, sendkeys, awtrobot

I need help with `Robot` class in Java. I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.delay(3000);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_7);
    r.delay(5000);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_7);
}
```

From what I understand, this code has to press "7" and release it after 5 seconds. But it presses "7" and then releases it immediately. So, `Robot` class doesn't press and release after a while, but it fires the key once instead.

How do I make my Java application to hold a key for few seconds, then release?

Comment: What is exactly your problem? What do you mean by it presses only one time as you only call keyPress once

Comment: I'm sorry for incorrect question. I've corrected. So I mean that Robot doesn't hold the key in "down position". It press and relese after pressing without keyRelease() command

Comment: Any chance it is your keyboard? I mean, do you get different results if you manually hold the `7` key for a seconds from releasing it immediately?

Comment: As I can understand you want to hold down the key for an x amount of time maybe this link will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784414/simulate-a-key-held-down-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after researching this topic closely, I have concluded that `java.awt.Robot` class just doesn't have the functionality to "hold" down the key.

The answer to a similar question ([Simulate a key held down in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784414/simulate-a-key-held-down-in-java)), which recommended me to create a loop of constantly repeating `keyPress` events, didn't satisfy me, since I needed a real key-hold simulation.

I also tried using [this library](https://github.com/Col-E/Simplified-JNA) with no success:

```java
Thread.sleep(3000);
Keyboard.sendKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_7);
Thread.sleep(5000);
Keyboard.sendKeyUp(KeyEvent.VK_7);
```

Finally, I solved my issue via [winKeyboard](https://github.com/umer0586/winKeyboard). But here's an **important note**:

I was developing a bot for a game, and was not trying to hold a key inside any text editor and see how it's continually filling the line with characters. If you'll try to test holding button within a text editor, it won't work, because text editors repeated key presses are working differently from normal keyboard events listeners in games. But it's a different topic.

### Solution:

```java
Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();

Thread.sleep(3000);
keyboard.winKeyPress(ScanCode.DIK_7);
Thread.sleep(5000);
keyboard.winKeyRelease(ScanCode.DIK_7);
```

Another thing to note is that sometimes, to make the bot work in games, you need to run your application as administrator, otherwise it might not work.